# Problem on Inclusion & Exclusion Principle

Tags: combinatorics, inclusion-exclusion

Book has the following & solution to it too, pls clear my confusion:

On rainy day , five gentlemen **A, B, C,D, E** attend a party after leaving their umbrellas in a checkroom. After the party is over, the umbrellas get mixed up and are returned to the gentlemen in such a manner that none receives his own umbrellas. In how many ways can this happen? Solution to this is follows:

Denote by $A_i$ the set if distribution in which the $ith$ gentlemen gets his umbrellas.

each $|A_i| = 24$

each $|A_i A_j| = 6$

each $|A_i A_j A_k| = 2$

each $|A_i A_j A_k A_l| = 1$

each $|A_1 A_2 A_3 A_4 A_5| = 1$

(sign between these is of intersection)

and hence the number of ways in which  none gets his umbrellas is equal to

$|A'_1 A'_2 A'_3 A'_4 A'_5| = 120 - \dbinom{5}{1} \times24 + \dbinom{5}{2} \times6 - \dbinom{5}{3} \times2 + \dbinom{5}{4} \times1 - 1$

What I don't understand is how $|A_i A_j| = 6$ and below this.

And why they had used $\dbinom{5}{1}$ and other such symbols.

Comment: If gentlemen $i$ and $j$ with $i\neq j$ get their own umbrella then there are $3!=6$ ways to divide the remaining umbrellas over the other gentlemen. Concerning $\binom51$: actually $120-|A_1|-|A_2|-\cdots-|A_5|\cdots$. But $|A_1|-|A_2|-\cdots-|A_5|=-5|A_1|$. Likewise $\binom52$ if two are picked from $5$ in the next term.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$|A_iA_j|=6$ because the $i$th and $j$th gentlemen must receive their own umbrellas, but the other three umbrellas can be permuted in $3!=3\cdot 2 \cdot 1 = 6$ ways among the remaining three gentlemen.

The binomial coefficients are used because the principle of inclusion/exclusion says that you must include all pairwise intersections, three way intersections, etc. It turns out all $n$-way intersections have the same size, which is why you can compute them generally as $|A_iA_j|$ or $|A_iA_jA_k|$, etc. But you also need to count *how many* such $n$-way intersections there are, which is $\binom{5}{n}$.